# Is there any simple wiki parsing opensource java service?

Tags: java, html, service, wiki

What I generally need is simple - opensource library with function that will turn given wiki mark up string into html. It shall work well with spark and red5 and Hibernate. 
It shall be tolerant to html objects inserts like YouTube videos, mathml and TeX inside that string.
So is there any such function in some JavaScript library?

Comment: Do you need some specific Wiki syntax, or can it by anything? Also, do you want this for Java or for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want this specifically for MediaWiki?  If yes, according to http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers, you've got two choices:

- http://www.wikiwyg.net/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:User:Pilaf/Live_Preview

Neither seems to do quite what you want, but they should be a useful starting point.